# asctime - day of month zero or space padded?

Tags: c, visual-c++, language-lawyer, msvcrt, time.h

I have the following program demonstrating the use of `asctime`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm   broken_down;
    broken_down.tm_year = 2000 - 1900;
    broken_down.tm_mon = 0;
    broken_down.tm_mday = 1;
    broken_down.tm_hour = broken_down.tm_min = broken_down.tm_sec = 0;

    printf("Current date and time: %s", asctime(&broken_down));
}
```

This program prints `Current date and time: Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 2000`, on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/6UtExr), i.e. the date field is space-padded.

When I compile and run this program with MSVC it produces the date string with leading zero on the day of month: `Current date and time: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 2000`.

What is the reason for this discrepancy? Which format is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As usual, the authors of Microsoft's (non-)standard C library have not given much thought to implementing the letter of standard correctly.

Even in the original standard [C89/C90](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html) the following text appears

> **Description**
>
> The `asctime` function converts the broken-down time in the structure
> pointed to by `timeptr` into a string in the form
>
> ```
> Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0
> ```
>
> using the equivalent of the following algorithm.
>
> ```
> char *asctime(const struct tm *timeptr)
> {
>     static const char wday_name[7][3] = {
>              "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
>     };
>     static const char mon_name[12][3] = {
>              "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
>              "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
>     };
>     static char result[26];
>
>     sprintf(result, "%.3s %.3s%3d %.2d:%.2d:%.2d %d\n",
>              wday_name[timeptr->tm_wday],
>              mon_name[timeptr->tm_mon],
>              timeptr->tm_mday, timeptr->tm_hour,
>              timeptr->tm_min, timeptr->tm_sec,
>              1900 + timeptr->tm_year);
>     return result;
> }
> ```

The example itself unfortunately uses a date that has a 2-digit day of month, but the code clearly uses `%3d` which means a decimal number without leading zeroes *space-padded and right-justified within a 3-character-wide field*.

The result for the given broken-down time is [`Sun Jan  1 00:00:00 2000`](https://ideone.com/0FoYs4) with space-padding.

---

Python 2, ever until 2.7.15 has been exposing the C standard library `asctime` output as-is, less the newline, which has caused platform-dependent behaviour. It was fixed in 2.7.15 to use a hard-coded format with leading space. The Python 2 documentation, too, uses a date with 2-digit day of month in its example, adding to further confusion.

Comment: Disagree with "have _not given much thought_ to implementing the letter of standard correctly.".  "What is the reason for this discrepancy?" --> Looks like   [EEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish)

Comment: @chux well... Hanlon's razor - maybe they haven't just noticed it in 30 years.

Comment: I suspect the source of _source_ error due to [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor), yet the _continuance_ of the discrepancy  is an intentional [exploit](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79589/51392)..